# Sign Up Forms to submit to different locations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

How to make a basic sign up form? If I used wordpress that would create a user on the wordpress website, but also submit the email that the user used to sign up, also submit to mailchimp or some sort of similar provider.

I tried googling it but I couldn't find any examples on what I want. If anyone knows something like this, could you please provide some examples I could read up on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'user_register' hook, it fires after user has registered with UserID as a param. More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Example of use:

```
function subscribeUser($userID) {
    /** @see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata */
    $userData = get_user_data($userID);
    $email = $userData->user_email;
    // Call your own function or SDK provider method
    subscribeMethod($email);
}
add_action('user_register', 'subscribeUser');
```

Hope this help you.

====

Maybe this plugin can help you: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-sync/